# How do I start thread only after first activity is finished?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

In my application I have scan button which scan qr code. Code is like this:

```
btnScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                            ClearForm();
                            //if (!CheckCHFID())return;

                            pd = ProgressDialog.show(EnquireActivity.this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.GetingInsuuree));
                            new Thread(){
                                public void run(){
                                    getInsureeInfo();

                                    pd.dismiss();
                                }
                            }.start();

                        }
                    });
```

Now the problem is before I scan the code it starts finding the information which is getInsureeInfo(); How can I control that it should execute only after user scans the code successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put it in `OnActivityResult` method ,ovveride it.

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
        case 1: 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //put your stuff here....

            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to move the part that you want to happen after the scan to the onActivityResult() method.

```
/*Here is where we come back after the Barcode Scanner is done*/
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // contents contains whatever the code was
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

            // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            // Handle successful scan. 

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel. If the user presses 'back' before a code is scanned.

        }
    }
}
```

Also I think you are going to have to use a Handler to send a message from the work thread to the main thread when it is time to hide your progress dialog. I don't think it will let you call dismiss on it from the background thread. That is just a hunch though, not tested.